# Applying Class to Customer Zend Decorator

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, decorator

I found code that would change the standard dt and dd tags to table tags for a Zend_Form_Element. Here is the code I used:

```
       $element->setDecorators(array(
   'ViewHelper',
   'Errors',
   array(array('data' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'td', 'class' => 'element')),
   array('Label', array('tag' => 'td', 'class' => 'rightAlign')),
   array(array('row' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'tr'))
```

));
But this puts the class name 'rightAlign' on the label tag instead of the td. I can't seem to wrap my head around these custom decorators so can anyone tell me how to get the class name 'rightAlign' on the td surrounding the label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add one more decorator

```
$element->setDecorators(array(
    'ViewHelper',
    'Errors',
    array(array('data' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'td', 'class' => 'element')),
    'Label',
    array(array('labelWrap' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'td', 'class' => 'rightAlign')),
    array(array('row' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'tr'))
));
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot. I really need to figure out how these decorators work properly lol.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->setElementDecorators(array(
                                            'ViewHelper',
                                            'Errors',
                                            array(array('data' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'td', 'class' => 'element')),
                                            array('Label',array('requiredSuffix' => ' * ')),
                                            array(array('labelWrap' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'td', 'align' => 'right')),
                                            array(array('row' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'tr'))
                                        ));
```

will add the required suffix ;)